# JavaFX RadioButton's not working correctly?

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button

So here is the UI portion of my program:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestClass extends Application {

Scene scene;
String fileName;
Button button;
Label fileLabel, dotText;
TextField fileNameText;
RadioButton totalRadio, aRadio, bRadio, cRadio;
ToggleGroup sumGroup;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane layout = new GridPane();
    layout.setVgap(5);
    layout.setHgap(5);

    //Adds button
    button = new Button("Sum file");
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        fileName = "C:\\Users\\Luke\\Desktop\\" + fileNameText.getText() + ".txt";
    });
    layout.setConstraints(button, 1, 1);

    //Adds label
    fileLabel = new Label("File name: ");
    layout.setConstraints(fileLabel, 0, 0);

    //Adds TextField
    fileNameText = new TextField();
    fileNameText.setPrefWidth(100);
    layout.setConstraints(fileNameText, 1, 0);

    //Adds Label
    dotText = new Label(".txt");
    layout.setConstraints(dotText, 2, 0);

    //Makes Button group
    sumGroup = new ToggleGroup();

    //Adding all radio buttons
    totalRadio = new RadioButton("Total");
    totalRadio.setToggleGroup(sumGroup);
    totalRadio.setSelected(true);
    layout.setConstraints(totalRadio, 1, 2);

    aRadio = new RadioButton("A Branch");
    totalRadio.setToggleGroup(sumGroup);
    layout.setConstraints(aRadio, 1, 3);

    bRadio = new RadioButton("B Branch");
    totalRadio.setToggleGroup(sumGroup);
    layout.setConstraints(bRadio, 1, 4);

    cRadio = new RadioButton("C Branch");
    totalRadio.setToggleGroup(sumGroup);
    layout.setConstraints(cRadio, 1, 5);

    //Adds components to scene
    layout.getChildren().addAll(fileLabel, fileNameText, button, dotText, totalRadio, aRadio, bRadio, cRadio);
    scene = new Scene(layout, 230, 185);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the Radiobuttons aren't working as they should. When you click a Button, it stays selected unless you click it again, and it won't de-select when another button is pressed. I've looked at many other threads, but most of them are just on how to add RadioButtons to ToggleGroup's, etc. I have the Toggle group, and added them, so what's wrong? (I'm learning JavaFX, I usually do GUI's in swing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting the totalRadio.setToggleGroup multiple times but not setting it on aRadio,bRadio,cRadio.

Change to:

```
aRadio = new RadioButton("A Branch");
aRadio.setToggleGroup(sumGroup);
layout.setConstraints(aRadio, 1, 3);

bRadio = new RadioButton("B Branch");
bRadio.setToggleGroup(sumGroup);
layout.setConstraints(bRadio, 1, 4);

cRadio = new RadioButton("C Branch");
cRadio.setToggleGroup(sumGroup);
layout.setConstraints(cRadio, 1, 5);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Details like that usually fly over my head when I copy and paste. I thought my problem was more of a settings type deal!